# HikariCP connection is not getting closed

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using HiKariConectionPooling in my spring-boot project. The open connection is not getting closed. Below are my Hikari properties used in the project:

> spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
>   spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
>   spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
>   spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
>   spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
>   spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000

Comment: You need to close connection in code

Comment: can you suggest how to close connection in code

Comment: Show your code so we can help